# Distinct polynomials with exactly one shared root

Tags: polynomials, roots

If $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are roots of a polynomial with rational coefficients is there a polynomial with rational coefficients for which $\alpha_1$ is a root but $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are not?

Comment: $x-\alpha_1{}{}$

Comment: I guess that's right. I didn't state the question exactly right though. I'll post an edit. I meant to be looking at polynomials with rational coefficients. I'm not sure how much harder that problem will be.

Comment: Are $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ all of the roots or just some selection of them?

Comment: Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't.  If you take $X^2+2$, then you aren't going to get $i\sqrt 2$ without $-i\sqrt 2$. You will run into this problem with any complex number.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ The polynomials $\,f\in \Bbb Q[x]\,$ having $\,\alpha\,$ as root are closed under  subtraction, and closed under multiplication by any other polynomial, so they are closed under gcd. Hence a minimal degree polynomial $\,g\,$ having $\,\alpha\,$ as root (e.g. an irreducible one) divides all other such polynomials. Equivalently, $\,f(\alpha) = 0\iff g\mid f\,$ in $\,\Bbb Q[x],\,$ where $\,g = \,$ minimal (irreducible) polynomial of $\,\alpha.$

**Remark** $\ $ If you know about ideals, then you may find it instructive to translate the above into ideal-theoretic language, using that $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ is Euclidean $\,\Rightarrow\,$ PID.

Comment: Better, because less complete, than the answer I had been preparing.

Answer (score 1):

No. $X^2 + 1$ is a counter example (to the edited question). For rational coeffiecents the polynomial must have both $i$ and the complex conjugate $-i$ as roots (if it has the other).